# Apache2, Wordpress, Ubuntu 16.04 TLS - URL issues

Tags: wordpress, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, php7

Could someone shed some light on this confusing issue I am having. I am using PHP7, Apache2, Ubuntu 16.04 TLS. When I type my web URL in www.example.co.uk this resolves to my apache default page which at the moment is fine. However, when i put in www.example.co.uk/wordpress/ my default site theme loads. The issue is when I click login to the admin panel, the page disappears. If I put the server IP address in like this ipaddress/wordpress/wp-admin/ the login page loads?

What am I missing here, as far as I can see I have done everything correctly. Probably something minor (usually is!) Could someone advise what the issue maybe?

Best Wishes, and thanks for reading

Comment: What means "the page disappears"? do you get a blank page, an error?

Comment: Yes a blank page. Then i press ctrl & u which brings up the html page, then I click the link <ipaddress>/wordpress/wp-login.php which then I can login. Really weird error!

Comment: Could you pls show here what the dev tool of the browser said? Usually is good idea see what is under curtain.

Comment: I am confused by that question? I have stated what services I am running on Ubuntu? You would like a screen shot of my error?

Comment: Correct, of the error that the browser give you when you access the network tab of the dev tool.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. The browser error shown: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>www.netasec.co.uk </title>
  
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://87.115.104.76" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 05 -->
<!-- -->
</html>

Comment: As seen above, I have to click the IP/wp-admin to load the page. The page will not load with my domain name/wp-admin? So kind of lost there

Answer (score 0):

Did you used this URL (http://ipaddress/wordpress/) during installation? If so then Wordpress stored this URL in your database.

Follow this guide to solve your issue:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: initially i used domainname/wordpress for installation. However, when I type the domain name, this works absolutely fine. I can see the default wordpress page. However, attempting to go to the admin login page it gives me a white screen. So I press ctrl and u and get the error as copied above. I then have to click ipaddress/wordpress/wp-admin and it works. Its an address mask issue?

Comment: weirdo!!! It seems that this URL is somehow mapped to a static html page that loads a frame which is not a standard wordpress behavior. Have you altered in any way your installation? Did you tried to deploy you site in another server? Maybe your hosting company is implementing a login protection mechanism

Comment: No this is the confusing part! I have recently switched to ubuntu, as always been a CentOS man personally. However, I am priviately hosting this on my pi at home. First time ive seen this issue! :(